# How to define a custom loss function for a multi-dimensional target

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, loss-function, tf.keras

I'm working with Tensorflow 2.0 and I'm using a normal sequential layer.

I'm trying to define a custom loss functions which does the following:

- takes some elements of the input
- computes their sum and invert the result
- multiplies the result with a part of y_pred
- constrain the result to be as close to 1 as possibile

Thus the loss function would be L() = MSE() +  (described above)

My code follows:

```
def custom_loss_wrapper(input_train):
    @tf.function
    def summing(row):
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(row, 1,keepdims=True)

    @tf.function
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        row_M = input_train
        row_M = row_M[:, 2:5]
        sum_M = summing(row_M)
        inv_M = (1/sum_M)

        row_B = y_pred[:, :3]
        sum_B = summing(row_B)

        row_Q = tf.math.multiply(inv_M,row_B)
        alpha = 0.01
        penalty =  K.mean(K.square(sum_Q - 1))

        return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) + (1/alpha) * penalty

    return custom_loss
```

I would like to understand if what I'm doing is right. There are not errors and the training runs, but I do not know if this piece of code does what I'm trying to define.  Mostly if this works correctly considering batches of data and not single records

Comment: If it works, why do you doubt that it works?

Comment: That's a good question! The problem is that I do not have a way to check if the training works as it would, I do not have a benchmark